# Control IE from hwnd

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

I have been trying to get this to work for days now.
My situation is that I have an excel document that needs browse a website as another windows user.

I have no problem controlling a webbrowser (IE) as the current user. But I cant launch or get the browser if I start it as another user.

I found a sample here: http://www.mvps.org/emorcillo/en/code/vb6/iedom.shtml but I cant take control of the elements on the page.

Almost all the code below is from that site except the last function test().

```
'
' Requires: reference to "Microsoft HTML Object Library"
'
Private Type UUID
   Data1 As Long
   Data2 As Integer
   Data3 As Integer
   Data4(0 To 7) As Byte
End Type

Private Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function GetClassName Lib "user32" _
   Alias "GetClassNameA" ( _
   ByVal hwnd As Long, _
   ByVal lpClassName As String, _
   ByVal nMaxCount As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function EnumChildWindows Lib "user32" ( _
   ByVal hWndParent As Long, _
   ByVal lpEnumFunc As Long, _
   lParam As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function RegisterWindowMessage Lib "user32" _
   Alias "RegisterWindowMessageA" ( _
   ByVal lpString As String) As Long

Private Declare Function SendMessageTimeout Lib "user32" _
   Alias "SendMessageTimeoutA" ( _
   ByVal hwnd As Long, _
   ByVal msg As Long, _
   ByVal wParam As Long, _
   lParam As Any, _
   ByVal fuFlags As Long, _
   ByVal uTimeout As Long, _
   lpdwResult As Long) As Long

Private Const SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG = &H2

Private Declare Function ObjectFromLresult Lib "oleacc" ( _
   ByVal lResult As Long, _
   riid As UUID, _
   ByVal wParam As Long, _
   ppvObject As Any) As Long

Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" _
   Alias "FindWindowA" ( _
   ByVal lpClassName As String, _
   ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

'
' IEDOMFromhWnd
'
' Returns the IHTMLDocument interface from a WebBrowser window
'
' hWnd - Window handle of the control
'
Function IEDOMFromhWnd(ByVal hwnd As Long) As IHTMLDocument
    Dim IID_IHTMLDocument As UUID
    Dim hWndChild As Long
    Dim lRes As Long
    Dim lMsg As Long
    Dim hr As Long

    If hwnd <> 0 Then
        If Not IsIEServerWindow(hwnd) Then
            ' Find a child IE server window
            EnumChildWindows hwnd, AddressOf EnumChildProc, hwnd
        End If

        If hwnd <> 0 Then

            ' Register the message
            lMsg = RegisterWindowMessage("WM_HTML_GETOBJECT")

            ' Get the object pointer
            Call SendMessageTimeout(hwnd, lMsg, 0, 0, _
                SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 1000, lRes)

            If lRes Then
                ' Initialize the interface ID
                With IID_IHTMLDocument
                    .Data1 = &H626FC520
                    .Data2 = &HA41E
                    .Data3 = &H11CF
                    .Data4(0) = &HA7
                    .Data4(1) = &H31
                    .Data4(2) = &H0
                    .Data4(3) = &HA0
                    .Data4(4) = &HC9
                    .Data4(5) = &H8
                    .Data4(6) = &H26
                    .Data4(7) = &H37
                End With

                ' Get the object from lRes
                hr = ObjectFromLresult(lRes, IID_IHTMLDocument, _
                    0, IEDOMFromhWnd)
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Function

Private Function IsIEServerWindow(ByVal hwnd As Long) As Boolean
Dim lRes As Long
Dim sClassName As String

   ' Initialize the buffer
   sClassName = String$(100, 0)

   ' Get the window class name
   lRes = GetClassName(hwnd, sClassName, Len(sClassName))
   sClassName = Left$(sClassName, lRes)

   IsIEServerWindow = StrComp(sClassName, _
                      "Internet Explorer_Server", _
                      vbTextCompare) = 0

End Function

'
' Copy this function to a .bas module
'
Function EnumChildProc(ByVal hwnd As Long, lParam As Long) As Long
    If IsIEServerWindow(hwnd) Then
        lParam = hwnd
    Else
        EnumChildProc = 1
    End If
End Function

Function test()
    Dim hwnd As Long
    Dim doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    hwnd = FindWindow("IEFrame", "Google - Internet Explorer")

    Set doc = IEDOMFromhWnd(hwnd)
    doc.execCommand "alert('test')"
End Function
```

It might have something to do with the fact that I get an Interface instead of an actual document, but I dont know how to change this.

Comment: That's VB code... Which versions of windows and IE are you using.. I think from memory VB6 requires the hwnd to be declared as a lPtr. The VB6 IDE has a debugger which you can place break points in. In your test function you should test for a hwnd value of 0... also (I think) nested quotes should be doubled... "alert('test')" s.b "alert(''test'')" ('' == two '). Visual Basic is no longer supported. You should abandon your work with it.

Comment: IE9 on Windows 7 does not append the string "Internet Explorer" to the end of the tabs document title. Use the spy++ utility that comes with Visual Studio to examine the window titles of the tabs under the Internet Explorer_server object.

Comment: the MVP site was last updated in 2000. I think you can safely give up on that code.